# How to save cluster assignments in output file using Weka clustering XMeans?

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, k-means, xmeans

**Context**

I want to use `Weka` clustering algorithm `XMeans`. However I cannot figure out how to obtain cluster assignments from `GUI of Weka`.

At the moment I can only see a list of cluster IDs along with percentage of entries assigned to each cluster.

**Question**

There any way to save cluster assignments for each entry in, e.g. `CSV` format?

Comment: Why don't you use the Java API? That is what it is good for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do everything in the "Preprocess Panel".

This is one way to do this:

- Load Data File.
- Remove any Classification Attribute or Identifiers
- Choose Preprocess / Filter / Unsupervised attribute Filter /
  AddCLuster
- Click on the Word "AddCluster", choose the XMeans Clusterer, click
  Apply.
- This sghould add a new column "cluster" in the Attribute Panel
- Click on "Save..." Button to export.

Comment: This is great, however sometimes when I do this I get different clustering results than I get in the Cluster tab, with all of the settings exactly the same (which produces the same results every time in the Cluster tab). What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Couldn't discover where is the fault.